# What is the relation between Old English fæsl and Proto-Indo-European *pes-?

Tags: etymology, cognates

The word in Proto-Indo-European *pes means penis. The other word "fæsl" means (according to oldenglishtranslator.uk) "seed [or] offspring". I can kind of see what the relationship could be (changing the p to an f, and sexual reproduction). Is that theory correct?

Comment: Cognates, according to this https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/pes-

Comment: Changing a PIE *p* to a Germanic *f* is entirely consistent with Grimm's Law, cf. Latin "pater" and English "father".

Answer (score 4):

Probably. Nothing's ever entirely certain when it comes to reconstruction, but comparison with Latin *pēni-* "penis" < PIt **pesni-*, Hittite *pesna-* "husband", Sanskrit *pasa-* "penis", and so on are pretty solid evidence for the PIE root, and PIE **p* > PGmc **f* word-initially is a famous and uncontroversial sound change.

Comment: Makes sense. I go it from Rebecca Monica's wiktionary source as well.